# How to convert a set to list ? The set is used as a key in Hashmap

Tags: java, android, list, hashmap, expandablelistview

Hi I an using an expandable listview in android. For populating the list I am using an hashmap as i want to map the corresponding categories to its child. My hashmap is like Hashmap> .Now the following code is used :

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 
{

    private Context _context;
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private Map<SaleDetailsMenuItems, List<ModifList>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, Map<SaleDetailsMenuItems, List<ModifList>> listChildData) 
    {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) 
    {
        Set<SaleDetailsMenuItems> s = _listDataChild.keySet();
        SaleDetailsMenuItems key = (SaleDetailsMenuItems) s.toArray()[groupPosition];
        //List<SaleDetailsMenuItems> list = new ArrayList<SaleDetailsMenuItems>(s);
        //Log.e("Child in adapter get Child","get child "+this._listDataChild.get(key).get(childPosititon));
        return this._listDataChild.get(key).get(childPosititon);
    }
    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
    {
        return childPosition;
    }
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

     String childText = ((ModifList)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).getName();
     String childText1 = "1";
     String childText2 = ((ModifList)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).getPrice();
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        TextView txtListChild1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem1);
        TextView txtListChild2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem2);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        txtListChild1.setText(childText1);
        txtListChild2.setText(childText2);
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        SaleDetailsMenuItems key ;
        try
        {
            Set<SaleDetailsMenuItems> s = _listDataChild.keySet();
        key = (SaleDetailsMenuItems) s.toArray()[groupPosition];
        //  List<SaleDetailsMenuItems> list = new ArrayList<SaleDetailsMenuItems>(s);
            //Log.e("Child size in adapter ","get children count "+this._listDataChild.get(key).size());
            this._listDataChild.get(key).size();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
        return this._listDataChild.get(key).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) 
    {
        Set<SaleDetailsMenuItems> s = _listDataChild.keySet();
        //List<SaleDetailsMenuItems> list = new ArrayList<SaleDetailsMenuItems>(s);
        SaleDetailsMenuItems key = (SaleDetailsMenuItems) s.toArray()[groupPosition];
        //Log.e("adapter get group ","get group "+key);
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() 
    {
        //Log.e("Group Count","Group Count "+_listDataChild.keySet().size());
        return _listDataChild.keySet().size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
         final int index = groupPosition;
        ExpandableListView mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
        mExpandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        TextView lblListHeader1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListquantity1);
        TextView lblListHeader2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListprice1);
        Button add = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        Button minus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Button01);


        lblListHeader.setText(((SaleDetailsMenuItems) getGroup(groupPosition)).getName().toString());
        lblListHeader1.setText(((SaleDetailsMenuItems) getGroup(groupPosition)).getQuantity().toString());
        lblListHeader2.setText(((SaleDetailsMenuItems) getGroup(groupPosition)).getPrice().toString());
        minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                putminusquantity(index);
        //listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Toast.makeText(context, shankar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //DeleteOrderScreen del = new DeleteOrderScreen();
                listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                putaddquantity(index);
                //listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() 
    {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this,set is used to get the keyset from Hashmap.as set is unordered i got the list in unordered form .I want the expandable list in ordered form. So how to make my list ordered?? Please reply me as soon as possible.

Comment: Ordered by what? Insertion?

Comment: I don't know if i understand your question properlly , but are you asking how to order a List<T> ?

Comment: entrySet() Returns a Set containing all of the mappings in this Map.

Comment: i want them to ordered by insertion...

Comment: @elvisrusu Yep but i am asking how to convert a set to list<t>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that you dont use HashMap or HashSet  but TreeMap and TreeSet.
eithe rthe objects you enter already have a correct compareTo methods, or You have to use a custom comparator which you provide in the constructor of TreeMap or TreeSet.

Then the map or set are sorted: Example:

```
   // auto sorted because Integer implements Comparable
    SortedSet set = new TreeSet<Integer>();

   // asume MyObject implements Comparable
   SortedSet set = new TreeSet<MyObject>();

   // asume MyObject needs a special other sorting
   SortedSet set = new TreeSet<MyObject>(MyCustomComparator);
```

similar for Maps:

```
 Map map = new TreeMap<Integer>;
```

or you also can use

```
SortedMap map = new TreeMap<Integer>;
```

Comment: Finally got the solution by myself by just modified my HashMap to LinkedHashMap, and converted my set to LinkedHashset as it allows me to insert the keys in inserted order..

Comment: The whole problem is solved by using Collections.synchronised map Concept in java.